# как узнать, что приложение удаляют И ВЫЗВАТЬ нужный метод при удалении?

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

по образцу одного из ответов написал код.
Не работает. Что-то сделал не так.
Прошу подсказать что сделал или не доделал.

---

алгоритм:

1. создал класс, унаследовал от BroadcastReceiver, прописал логику при onReceive
2. объявил в манифесте

---

1. создаю класс и наследую его от BroadcastReceiver.
   Задача класса - при удалении приложения отправить в Firebase запись со значением deviceID.
   (в дальнейшем,  в Firebase будет просто удалятся пользователь с нужным deviceID)
   а пока в примере просто создаётся новая ветка (child "deletedUser") с deviceID пользователя

   ```
    public class UninstalAppReceiverSam extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public DatabaseReference REF_users_deleted;                // создаю ссылку на ветку в базе
    private String key_dletedUsers = "deleted_users";          // ветка с удалёнными пользователями

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver") 
    @Override                                                  // переопределяю onReceive
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getDataString().equals("package:com.sambor.test")){
            REF_users_deleted = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(key_dletedUsers);
            String deviceID = "123";
            UserClass user = new UserClass(deviceID);         // создаю класс
            REF_users_deleted.push().setValue(user);          // отправяю в Firebase
        }

        // здесь:
        // com.sambor - это имя пакета
        // test - название приложения

    }
    }
   ```

   //2. манифест (в зоне application)

   ```
    <application

     <receiver android:name = "com.sambor.test.UninstalAppReceiverSam">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>
   ```

Comment: Миллиард лет назад я задавал аналогичный вопрос на enSo и ценой 500 очков я получил на него [корректный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816716/472270)

Comment: попробовал.  Пишут что GET_TASKS устарел   ... и пока не разобрался чем и как его заменить. (благодарю за ответ)